# How to fix an issue with customizer live preview?

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer, css

I am attempting to create customizable theme for my clients. The goal is to enable them to modify certain styles inside the theme customizer.

I didn't want to insert customizer's variables inside html code, but instead created a `css-php` file. Everything works well except that live preview of the changes doesn't reflect them in real time. Instead I have to refresh the page each time after single change. It doesn't bother me personally but it annoys my clients.

What are your thoughts on this?

Thats what I have in my `functions.php`:

```
function im_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {

$colors = array();
$colors[] = array(
  'slug'=>'im_header_bcolor', 
  'default' => '#556d80',
  'label' => __('Header Background Color', 'impressive')
);
$colors[] = array(
  'slug'=>'im_nav_bar_bcolor', 
  'default' => '#434044',
  'label' => __('Navigation Bar Background Color', 'impressive')
);
foreach( $colors as $color ) {
  // SETTINGS
  $wp_customize->add_setting(
    $color['slug'], array(
      'default' => $color['default'],
      'type' => 'theme_mod', 
      'capability' => 
      'edit_theme_options'
    )
  );
  // CONTROLS
  $wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Color_Control(
      $wp_customize,
      $color['slug'], 
      array('label' => $color['label'], 
      'section' => 'colors',
      'settings' => $color['slug'])
    )
  );
}

}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'im_customize_register' );


function im_theme_styles() {

wp_enqueue_style( 'main_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'im_theme_styles' );

$custom_css= '
  .im_header { background-color: ' . get_theme_mod('im_header_bcolor') . '; }
  .im_nav_bar { background-color: ' . get_theme_mod('im_nav_bar_bcolor') . '; }
  ';

wp_add_inline_style ('main-style', $custom_css);
```

And my `css.php`:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8"); ?>

<?php

  $parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
  require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );

  $im_header_bcolor = get_theme_mod('im_header_bcolor');
  $im_nav_bar_bcolor = get_theme_mod('im_nav_bar_bcolor');

?>



  .im_header { background-color:  <?php echo $im_header_bcolor; ?>; }
  .im_nav_bar { background-color:  <?php echo $im_nav_bar_bcolor; ?>; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up a `css.php` for this purpose is overkill (or undesirable in any case, as @MarkKaplun states in the other answer).

The smoothest way for previews of css is using jquery (see [part 3 of the customizer API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API)).

Since you're not using the `transport` argument in your setting, the page is reloaded anyway, so you can simply add the styles in your `functions.php` using [`wp_add_inline_style`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style), inside the function that enqueues your `style.css`. Like this:

```
add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts','wpse242256_add_styles');

function wpse242256_add_styles () {
  wp_enqueue_style('main-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
  $custom_css= '
    .im_header { background-color: ' . get_theme_mod('im_header_bcolor') . '; }
    .im_nav_bar { background-color: ' . get_theme_mod('im_nav_bar_bcolor') . '; }
    ';
  wp_add_inline_style ('main-style', $custom_css);
}
```

Comment: Given that I added code to the function, should it be something like this `wp_enqueue_style( 'main_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('main-style'), false, all );` ?

Comment: Yes, you should allready be adding an action to load `style.css` in your theme. You load the inline styles immediately after that.

Comment: Note that if you don't specifiy a default in the setting, `get_theme_mod` might return empty and you end up with invalid css.

Comment: It doesn't appear to work, i'll update the whole thing in my question

Comment: That line you give in the first comment won't load `style.css`, because it's dependent on something that probably isn't there.

Comment: Yeah i got it :) Please scroll down the functions.php code in the question to see the whole thing.

Comment: There you use `main_css` as the handle for `style.css`, but you are addressing it as `main-style` in `wp_add_inline_style`. The second handle must be the same as the first. I've updated my answer to show it in more detail.

Comment: Yeah, i've read documentation for that function and I got it to work. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `css.php` style files. They are hard to write correctly and provide yet another security concern. In some settings running php directly from a theme's directory will just be forbidden at the server level.

Always follow what core themes do, inventing your own things is nice and creative, but it will annoy the hell out of whoever will need to maintain your themes for the clients.

Comment: so you advise inserting custom style inside `<head>` tags or inside elements tags? If I was to maintain that theme that would've pissed me off even more than separate clean `css.php`.

Comment: plus everything works well with css php file. Except for the live preview.

Comment: when you develop for wordpress you should follow the wordpress standards.

Comment: your css.php works only on your specific setting and will probably break for 5% of the sites, maybe more

Comment: I doubt it. Even if css.php for some reason wouldn't work all styles would fall back to default values from style.css.

Comment: The point of the customizer is to have a true live preview. if you use two different code paths it is a semi live preview. (for which I do prefer to do a page refresh instead of the faster methods)